# jQuery iterate on all fixed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to "move" all fixed elements in jQuery. This is what I tried:

```
jQuery('body *').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.attr('position') !== undefined)
    {
        $this.css('margin-top', 50);
    }
});
```

but unfortunatly it wont work, `$this.attr('position')` is always `undefined`. But it is set on some elements. (from CSS, not inline)

Comment: I don't know about the `position` attribute so far. Did you try it with `$this.css('position')`?

Comment: @31piy: yyyyaaaayyyyyyy........... it explaines everything. Now it works...... (for punishment no more questions, for a week :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `position` is a CSS property, not a HTML attribute, so `attr()` will not work with it. Secondly, CSS properties are never `undefined`. They always have default values, although it looks from your question title that you want `'fixed'` elements instead:

```
$('body *').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('position') === 'fixed';
}).css('margin-top', '50px');
```

It should be noted, however, that this is very far from an ideal solution. I'd strongly suggest putting a class, or some other identifier, on the elements you want to amend and then add a `class` to them which sets the `margin-top`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [.css() style property](http://api.jquery.com/css/) of jquery to check this.

```
jQuery('body *').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    if ($this.css('position') !== undefined)
    {
        $this.css('margin-top', 50);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate all document elements with just a `*`.
To get the value of css you need to use `css()` method in the `if` to check the value of property instead of attr. I made a working example for you, hope it helps:

```js
$('*').each(function(){
    if ($(this).css('position') == "fixed"){
        $(this).css('margin-top', 50);
        $(this).css('color', "red");
    }
});
```

```css
.a{
   position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>My test 1</span>
<span>My test 2 </span>
<span class="a">My test 3 </span>
<span>My test 4</span>
<span>My test 5</span>
<span class="a">My test 6</span>
<span>My test 7</span>
```

Comment: include jquery in snippet

Comment: Also 'try this' isn't very helpful. It doesn't educate the OP, or any future visitors, about what the error is and why it was a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Updated answer.